# Is it better to have one setter method or multiple for objects with a fixed number of fields?

Tags: javascript, architecture, readability, maintainability

I have a class with a member variable of type object. This object has a fixed number of fields. I'm trying to decide if I should use one setter function or multiple to mutate these fields.

To make the question more concrete, I've written the following class to model a simple organizational management structure in two different ways:

1. Multiple Setter Functions

   ```
   class Management {
       constructor() {
           this.numberOfManagers = 100;
           this.salaryDetails = {
               regionalManagerSalary: 80000,
               stateManagerSalary: 110000,
               executiveManagerSalary: 200000
           };
       }

       setRegionalManagerSalary(salary) {
           this.salaryDetails.regionalManagerSalary = salary;
       }

       setStateManagerSalary(salary) {
           this.salaryDetails.stateManagerSalary = salary;
       }  

       setExecutiveManagerSalary(salary) {
           this.salaryDetails.executiveManagerSalary = salary;
       }
   }

   const management = new Management();
   management.setRegionalManagerSalary(100000);
   management.setStateManagerSalary(120000);
   management.setExecutiveManagerSalary(210000);
   ```
2. One Setter Function

   ```
   class Management {
       constructor() {
           this.numberOfManagers = 100;
           this.salaryDetails = {
               regionalManagerSalary: 80000,
               stateManagerSalary: 110000,
               executiveManagerSalary: 200000
           };
       }

       setManagerSalary(typeOfManagerSalary, salary) {
           this.salaryDetails[typeOfManagerSalary] = salary;
       }
   }

   const management = new Management();
   management.setManagerSalary('regionalManagerSalary', 100000);
   management.setManagerSalary('stateManagerSalary', 120000);
   management.setManagerSalary('executiveManagerSalary', 210000);
   ```

Would implementation 1. be better or would implementation 2. be better?

Comment: I think 2 would be better. Less lines of code with readabilty as well

Comment: However, if you have the requirement where the values to be set have to be checked or filtered than the same code sample 2 will become complicated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will always consider the higher readability approach if it doesn't trade off a lot of writability. The second one is more generic but the first one is more clear.

So I think the first one is better as it is more clear that there are only 3 fields in `salaryDetails`. Just consider you are not the author and when you see the second one, you have no idea how many fields there will be in `salaryDetails` as someone could just call `management.setManagerSalary('someNewSalary', 100000);` somewhere to add some new fields.

Unless you have more than one Management objects and each of them might have some specific fields under `salaryDetails`, I don't think the second approach is better.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to have one method say setSalaryDetails which will take salary object as input which you can set directly. Something like -

setSalaryDetails(salaryDetails){this.salaryDetails = salaryDetails; }

When you invoke this method you can appropriately create this object with those fields set that you will pass to it.

Comment: This is dangerous in that the caller might not know the exact structure of salaryDetails. The caller could pass an object with a missing field or overwrite an existing field unintentially.

Comment: No, because in the current code also, the caller needs to know the property/key he needs to set. If the caller is aware of one property, why wouldn't he be unaware of other properties. If this code is part of a library, its expected we share the JSON contract with the consumers (just like you do for REST services). The caller and callee needs to mutually agree on the contract. So this is not dangerous et.al.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to not have any setter at all. Initialize all the required properties in the constructor (let the constructor require arguments for this).

The code you posted it not OOP but procedural code under disguise. If you want to make it OOP then the code must stay where the data is, i.e. in the class.

As a first improvement step, your code should look like this:

```
class Management {
    constructor(nb, regionalSalary, stateSalary, executiveSalary) {
        this.numberOfManagers = nb;
        this.salaryDetails = {
            regionalManagerSalary: regionalSalary,
            stateManagerSalary: stateSalary,
            executiveManagerSalary: executiveSalary
        };
    }
}

const management = new Management(100, 100000, 120000, 210000);
```

Shorter, much cleaner, less error prone.

The fragment you posted is not enough to tell what you want to achieve but the new signature of the constructor tells me that you are mixing too many responsibilities into a single class.

A cleaner design is to use separate classes for each manager type:

```
/* abstract */ class Manager {
    constructor(salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}

class RegionalManager extends Manager { }
class StateManager extends Manager { }
class ExecutiveManager extends Manager { }

class Management {
    constructor(nb, regionalManager, stateManger, executiveManager) {
        this.numberOfManagers = nb;
        this.managers = {
            regionalManager: regionaManager,
            stateManager: stateManager,
            executiveManager: executiveManager
        };
    }
}

const management = new Management(
    100,
    new RegionalManager(100000),
    new StateManager(120000),
    new ExecutiveManager(210000)
);
```

You can now implement the logic common to all manager types in class `Manager`, the logic that is specific to each manager type in its class and the logic that handles the managers by number, without caring about their individual characteristics, in class `Management`. This way the code uses less `if` and `switch` conditions, is easier to read, understand and develop further.